# How to use stopifnot with a list in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of vectors. Suppose further that I would like to have a condition based on their length. That is, I would like my function return an error if the lengths of these vectors are not equal.

For example,

`x <- c(1:4)`
`y <- c(1:5)`
`z <- c(1:4)`
`k <- list(x, y, z)`

I would like to check that their lengths are equal.

`stopifnot(length(k[[1]]) == length (k[[2]]) == length(k[[3]]))`

How could I generalize this code and make it works for an arbitrary number of elements of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lengths` with `unique`

```
stopifnot(length(unique(lengths(k)))==1)
```

> Error: length(unique(lengths(k))) == 1 is not TRUE

The `lengths` will get the `length` of each of the `vector` in the `list` as a `vector`, get the `unique` and check if the `length` is equal to 1.  If it is not i.e. `stopifnot`, give an error

Comment: amazing. Thanks so much.